# How to use a user inputted value from a textbox in a variable (Powershell)

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm having the hardest time getting a value from a text box to use in another function. If I step through the script, I can see that the value is assigned to the text box, but am not able to assign it to another variable.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#region XMLCode

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PayrollApp"
        Title="Payroll Application" Height="450" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Computer Name:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="txtComputerName" Margin="120,5,5,5" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Site ID:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Name="txtSiteID" Margin="120,5,5,5"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Payroll ID:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="txtPayrollID" Margin="120,5,5,5"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="4" Content="Email From Address:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Name="txtFromAddress" Margin="120,5,5,5"/>
            <Separator Grid.Row="5" Margin="5"/>
            <TabControl Grid.Row="6" Margin="5">
                <TabItem Header="Daily Payroll">
                    <StackPanel Background="LightGray">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        Use this form to re-run the Daily Payroll file.
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Margin="5,0">
                        Enter the dates (YYYYMMDD) needed in the boxes below and press "Send"
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Name="txtDaily1" Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtDaily2" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtDaily3" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtDaily4" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtDaily5" Margin="5"/>
                        <Button Name="btnDailySend" Margin="5" Width="75" Background="BurlyWood">Send</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Weekly Payroll">
                    <StackPanel Background="LightGray">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            Use this form to re-run the Weekly Payroll file.
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Margin="5,0">
                        Enter the date of the payroll period (Wednesday) (YYYYMMDD) and press "Send"
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Name="txtWeekly" Margin="5"/>
                        <Button Name="btnWeeklySend" Margin="5,10" Width="75" Background="BurlyWood">Send</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

#endregion

#region LoadWindow

#Read the XAML file
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try {
    $window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
}
catch {
    ThrowError -ErrorObj $_
}

# Create variables based on form control names
# Variable will be named as 'var_<control name>'

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
    #"trying item $($_.Name)"
    try {
        Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        ThrowError $_
    }
}

# Get-Variable var_*

#endregion

#region EventsAndMethods

$window.Add_Loaded({
    
    # Get the site information
    GetSiteInformation
    # Populate the text boxes
    $var_txtComputerName.Text = $computer
    $var_txtPayrollID.Text = $global:payid
    $var_txtSiteID.Text = $global:SiteNum
    $var_txtFromAddress.Text = $script:from

    # Get the number of daily text boxes
    $global:numDailyTextBox = (Get-Variable -Name "var_txtDaily*").Count
})

$var_btnDailySend.Add_Click({
    # Email contents
    $body = "PeopleSoft Team,`r`nHere are the time punch files that need to be uploaded to PeopleSoft.`r`nThanks."
    $sub = "cctime Files for $sitename $payrollid"

    $timefiles = @()

    # Run the Payroll 
    $dailyTextBox = @(Get-Variable -Name "var_txtDaily*")

    foreach ($textBox in $dailyTextBox) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($textBox.Text)) {
            continue
        }
        
        $date = $textBox.Text
        RunDailyPayroll -day $date

        LogInfo "Moving time file to C:\TA"
        Move-Item -Path "$script:filepath\$script:dailyfile" -Destination $scriptPath -Force -Verbose
    }

    LogInfo "Sending email"
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $script:from -SmtpServer $server -Subject $sub -Body $body -Attachments "$scriptPath\$script:dailyfile" -Verbose
    LogInfo "Email sent"
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Email sent!", "OkOnly", "Email sent")
    
})
```

The issue is in the `$var_btnDailySend.Add_Click` event. There are 5 text boxes where the user will enter data into 1 or more of them. I then want to use that value in the `RunDailyPayroll` function. But I cannot assign that value to another variable. When stepping through, the value is: `System.Windows.Controls.Text::<value entered>`. How can I convert that to a string of just the `<value entered>`? And I've tried `$date = $textBox.Text.ToString()`, which just throws an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$TextBox.Value.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to extract the text with

```
$TextBox.Value.Text
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help!